# From a Java programming perspective, what difference does multicast make to a networking program?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, sockets, multicast

My manager has asked me to assess what changes would be required to add multicast support to a socket-based TCP/IP networking program that is part of a trading system.

As far as I can tell, from the perspective of a Java program, it doesn't seem to matter too much whether the program is unicast or multicast.

Doesn't the Java networking API make all of this transparent? By this I mean, wouldn't the change be a simple one of simply adding additional destinations for the outgoing connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, TCP doesn't have support for multicast. Multicast is often done via UDP. [UDP by design is not a reliable transport](http://roseindia.net/javatutorials/multicasting_in_java.shtml). I-e there is no guarantee of datagram reaching its destination and there is no delivery report when it does reach the destination.

Some reliable multicast solutions are discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453109/tcp-multicast-and-multithreading) but they are in-essence different protocols.

So if you your application needs to guarantee delivery while using multicast, you will certainly need do some changes in your communication layer.

Comment: There is also no guarentee of order.

Comment: 'TCP doesn't have support for multicast'. Correct. TCP is a point-to-point, i.e. unicast, protocol.