# psuedo TCP multicast with os.dup2() in python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, multicast, dup2

The idea is to *multicast* the same content from one single resource to multiple receivers at once. I came up with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8

import socket, os

c = socket.socket()
c.connect(('127.1', 4343))

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('127.1', 8989))
s.listen(3)
while 1:
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  print 'Connected by %s:%s' % addr
  os.dup2(conn.fileno(), c.fileno(), )
s.close()
```

I tested it with `netcat` without any success, either the `client` quits unexpected or the `server` exits after anything connects. Is this possible at all? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `os.dup2()` call both file descriptors (FDs) refer to the same socket, thus sharing its buffers. When data is extracted (via `recv()` or `read()`) using original FD, this fragment can no longer be extracted using duplicated FD, and vice versa. Each octet of incoming data will be read exactly once and by a single receiver, it won't be duplicated for each FD (that's where you are mistaken, I suppose).

For reliable multicast solutions see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466506/3398329) and the linked topic.